# AdonisJs: Route.on() vs Route.get()

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

Dealing with [AdonisJs](https://adonisjs.com/) framework, I wonder what is the difference between `Route.on()` and `Route.get()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found answer in the official [routing](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/routing) documentation:

> For static pages, you don’t necessarily need logic and directly want
>   to render a view. This can be achieved by using `Router.on().render()`.